# Vanishing particular solution for $yy'-ay=-bx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation of the form:
$$y\frac{dy}{dx}-ay=-bx$$
where both both $a$ and $b$ are known real numbers
$$a,b\neq0.$$
When I attempt to solve this with a particular solution of:
$$y_p=Cx+D$$
Results to
$$CD-aD=0$$
$$C^2-aC=-b$$
By inspection, we can say that:
$$C=a$$
But this does not make sense since:
$$0=-b$$
Which is impossible!

I even tried using quadratic but same thing. This looks very simple, but I am now a bit lost here, what is the best way to solve this differential equation?

Comment: I tried that but same thing, it results to $v'=0$, on the other hand $v\neq0$ since $v = a$

Comment: I used the general form $y=vx+A$, could this be possibly wrong too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$yy'-ay=-bx$$
Try $y=kx$
$$k^2x-akx=-bx$$
$$k^2-ak+b=0$$
Solve for $k$. $k$ depends on both $a$ and $b$.
$$\Delta = a^2-4b \;\;,k=\dfrac {a \pm \sqrt {\Delta}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y(x)y'(x)-ay(x)+bx=0$$ is not an easy one. May be they are some tricks I miss but I give you my attemps
$$y=\frac 1 2x(z(x)+a) \implies(4b-a^2)+x (a+z(x)) z'(x)+z(x)^2=0$$ Switch variables
$$(4b-a^2)+\frac{x(z)}{x'(z)}(a+z)+z^2=0$$
$$x(z)=e^{u(z)}\implies (4b-a^2)+\frac{a+z}{u'(z)}+z^2=0$$ which is separable
$$u'(z)=\frac{a+z}{(a^2-4 b)-z^2}$$
$$u(z)+C=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left((4b-a^2)+z^2\right)-\frac{a }{\sqrt{4 b-a^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{4
   b-a^2}}\right)$$